# Prove that the characteristic of Z/mZ × Z/nZ equals D, where D is the least common multiple between m and n

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have no idea to go about the proof. Intuitively, I understand that the characteristic is the point where elements start repeating themselves, and of course for the elements in Z/m X Z/n to start repeating themselves, it will only occur once we hit their least common multiple.

I just don't know how to write out the proof formally or what the notation would be.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $D$ denote the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$.

- Show that the element $(1,1)$ has order $D$.
- Show that for any $g \in \Bbb Z_m \times \Bbb Z_n$, $g^D = (0,0)$.

Comment: To show that the order of element (1,1) is D, do I just keep adding 1 to itself until I get D? How do I do this if I do not know what D is? Is there a better way of finding the order of an element?

Comment: That's the idea.  Notice, however, that you only get a $0$ in the first slot if you add a multiple of $m$ times.  Similarly, you only get a $0$ in the second slot if you add a multiple of $n$ times.